# Which Language Google Uses For Web Applications

Tags: web-applications, programming-languages

I want to know one thing, which language Google uses for web application development, because i was discussing with my friends about this and they say that Google uses Python for web applications, but which is it?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are very pro-Python, definitely seem to be the direction they are headed.

Clearly they have a lot of their development also invested in JavaScript APIs!

It seems to me like the projects that are 'for internal use, gone public' have both Java and Python APIs, which strongly suggest they do both Python and Java in-house.

Comment: Why do you care so much? If a rep from google doesn't come in and answer the question, then an educated guess is the next best thing.

Comment: +1 @kinopiko I think you were a bit too strict on that one, if we really want to answer we have to work at google and probably nobody does so that just opinion and best guess.

Comment: Like Jon Skeet, who does C# :P

Answer (score 7):

I recall reading somewhere (Steve Yegge?) that the "official" languages at Google include Python, Java, and C++, JavaScript. I believe GMail is written with a Java backend. [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html) is Java compiled to JavaScript.

Comment: Most educated answer so far. Google's core operations such as search are done mostly in C++, plumbing stuff is Python and Java and JavaScript/DHTML is used to tie things together from web perspective. Interesting stack of technologies for various uses IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [Greg Stein](http://panela.blog-city.com/python_at_google_greg_stein__sdforum.htm), bolding is mine :

> **At Google, *python* is one of the 3
>   "official languages" alongside with
>   *C++* and *Java***.  Official here means
>   that Googlers are allowed to deploy
>   these languages to production
>   services.  (**Internally Google people
>   use many technologies including *PHP*,
>   *C#*, *Ruby* and *Perl***).  Python is well
>   suited to the engineering process at
>   Google.

Answer (score 0):

I think lot of things including Python, Java, maybe some PHP and maybe some ruby on rails.

Comment: But Python is the first choice of they?

Comment: -1 What's the point of guessing? What's the point of upvoting a guess?

Comment: It is very well documented that there are only four languages allowed at Google: C++, Java, Python, ECMAScript. So, this is just plainly wrong: there is no PHP or Ruby at Google. In fact, Steve Yegge famously ported Rails to ECMAScript just so that he could use Rails at Google.

Comment: Do they really say "ECMAScript" at Google?

Answer (score 0):

Their web applications that use the [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) is programmed in Java. The GWT then compiles the Java into a combination of JavaScript and DHTML that is cross platform compatible.

Comment: Majority? What other apps besides the AdWords and Google Wave that uses GWT?